# Handling string with delimiters in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I need to pass string with delimiter as argument to python script. So, I used

```
parser.add_argument('--filter', default=None, nargs='*', action="append")
```

The input to the script can be any of the following:

```
process.py --filter include:a.txt,b.txt exclude:c.txt, d.txt
process.py --filter a.txt   => This should be considered as include:a.txt
process.py --filter include:b.txt --filter exclude:d.txt
process.py --filter exclude:c.txt --filter b.txt
```

The files a.txt, b.txt, c.txt and d.txt contains some strings with regex patterns.

I need to filter a report based on the keywords (include/exclude). In first two cases above, only one report needs to be generated after filtering whereas two reports needs to be generated in third and fourth cases. So, I need to store the given input as

```
Case 1:
filter1 => include => a.txt, b.txt
           exclude => c.txt, d.txt

Case 2:
filter1 => include => a.txt

Case 3:
filter1 => include => b.txt
filter2 => exclude => d.txt

Case 4:
filter1 => exclude => c.txt
filter2 => include => b.txt
```

How can I achieve storing the values as defined above?

Thanks.

Comment: you sure you want your filters be --filter1 --filter2 etc? or would a list of filters be better? Either way i suggest looking into: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action there is an example of custom action at the bottom of this section, this should enable you to do what you want

Comment: Experiment to see what you get in `sys.argv` with various inputs.  You may need more quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your argument, and command lines I get

```
Namespace(filter=[['include:a.txt,b.txt', 'exclude:c.txt,', 'd.txt']])
Namespace(filter=[['a.txt']])
Namespace(filter=[['include:b.txt'], ['exclude:d.txt']])
Namespace(filter=[['exclude:c.txt'], ['b.txt']])
```

These values closely reflect what the parser got in `sys.argv[1:]`.

It should be easy to process that `filter` list to generate the values you want.  You don't need to do any thing more in `argparse`.  Trying to do it in `argparse` will not save any effort or logic.

That said, I can think of some things that would make the logic simpler.

Eliminate the space in `exclude:c.txt, d.txt`. or put quotes around that substring.

Drop the implicit `include` requirement.

Instead of one `--filter` option, define two, `--include` and `--exclude` options (and maybe a positional to handle the implicit 'include'):

```
parser.add_argument('--include','-i', default=[], nargs='*', action="append")
parser.add_argument('--exclude','-e', default=[], nargs='*', action="append")
parser.add_argument('include', nargs='*', action="append")
```

producing

```
'a.txt' => 
Namespace(exclude=[], include=[['a.txt']])

'--include a.txt b.txt --exclude c.txt d.txt' =>
Namespace(exclude=[['c.txt', 'd.txt']], include=[['a.txt', 'b.txt'], []])
```

---

A simple function to parse the `filter` values:

```
def decode(values):
    filters = []
    for f in values:
        filter = {}
        for text in f:
            words = text.split(':')
            if len(words)==1:
                words = ['include']+words
            files = words[1].split(',')
            if words[0] == 'include':
                filter['include'] = files
            elif words[0] == 'exclude':
                filter['exclude'] = files
            else:
                filter['unknown'] = files
        filters.append(filter)
    return filters
```

Which can be used as:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
filters = decode(args.filter)
```

producing for your 4 cases:

```
[{'exclude': ['c.txt', 'd.txt'], 'include': ['a.txt', 'b.txt']}]
[{'include': ['a.txt']}]
[{'include': ['b.txt']}, {'exclude': ['d.txt']}]
[{'exclude': ['c.txt']}, {'include': ['b.txt']}]
```

I think the only thing this misses is handling the space in `exclude:c.txt, d.txt`.  For that it produces: `[{'exclude': ['c.txt', ''], 'include': ['d.txt']}]`.  That is, it interprets that as an implicit `include`.

In theory it could be included in a custom Action for the `--filter` argument, but I think it works just as well after parsing.